# Validating Textboxes and skipping Validations on form close

Tags: c#, regex, validation

Following is the code snippet that I am using to validate my textboxes.

C# Code

```
private void TxtEmail_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{

    string StrEmail = TxtEmail.Text.Trim();
    if (StrEmail == "" || StrEmail.IndexOf("") > 0 || StrEmail.IndexOf('"') > 0 || StrEmail == " " || StrEmail.IndexOf(" ") > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Email Cannot be Left Blank");
        TxtEmail.Select();

    }

    Regex r = new Regex(@"@.");

    if (r.IsMatch(TxtEmail.Text))
    {
        AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email Format");
        TxtEmail.Clear();
        TxtEmail.Focus();
    }

 }

private void TxtPassword_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string StrPass=TxtPassword.Text;
    if (StrPass == "" || StrPass.IndexOf("") > 0 || StrPass.IndexOf('"') > 0 || StrPass == " " || StrPass.IndexOf(" ") > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password");
        TxtPassword.Focus();
    }

    Regex r = new Regex(@"@#");
    if (r.IsMatch(TxtPassword.Text))
    {

        AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable;

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password");
        TxtPassword.Clear();
        TxtPassword.Focus();

    }


}
```

I am using `AutoValidate` feature to cancel validation if the parameters within the Regex match.But the problem is when I use `AutoValidate or Set CauseValidation to false`,the validation of TextBox is done the first time the form is loaded. But when I remove the text within the texbox and re-enter it, validation doesn't work the 2nd time and does not throw the message `"Invalid Email"`

In the case of Password Validation.Even after entering password as per the parameters within the Regex,it throws `"Invalid Password"` message.I saw questions here based on validation but none of them have satisfactory solution to my question.

Can anyone help me to rectify this error? I want to achieve Validation without ErrorProvider which is another option.

Comment: Try the Validating event instead of Validated

Comment: @Sybren I used Validating for Validating email ,but its not working.